# zend framework 2 error reporting

Tags: php, error-handling, zend-framework2

I'm having some problems getting zf2 to log errors or report them under some circumstances.

Some errors will be reported to screen and the error.log but others are not and just result in a blank screen. There doesn't appear to be any reasoning behind what does get displayed and what doesn't.

I have error reporting enabled in my php ini set to E_ALL and I have added

```
'display_not_found_reason' => true,
'display_exceptions'       => true,
```

to my module config, and I have also tried setting the error reporting values directly in the index.php

At the moment im trying to use doctrine and just getting a blank screen...

Comment: have you enabled display_errors in php.ini?

Comment: 90% when you add a module , if you are getting blank page then the reason is module is not loaded properly this is the errorlog you receive in apache error log , so you can use Zend developer toolbar to debug this

Comment: Also Service manager of ZF2 is not yet evolved so much to report module specific problems I think .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://packagist.org/packages/webino/nette-debug

Link listed above is one of the most useful debug tools I've found so far for zf2.  It picks up 99.9% of the errors and the configuration allows you to log it to a specific log file in your directory.  However there is that .1% that it doesn't catch and that generally does go through to the syslog so you should be able to find out more details there.  Just make sure you initialize the nette debug module as the first module in the stack.

Hope this helps you, I got really sick and tired of those issues too up to the point where where I found nette.